# Dagger2 Why can't one type is injected into more than one component?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

In Dagger2 is it possible to request same class for injection from more than one component. Sample code below

```
@Component(modules = classA.class)
interface compA
{
void inject(MyActivity target);
}

@Component(modules = classB.class)
interface compB
{
void inject(MyActivity target);
}
```

If possible please explain with reason and any doc reference.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have multiple components like that. :| this use-case would demand `Subcomponents for encapsulation` as per https://google.github.io/dagger//subcomponents.html

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you please show an example for above using subcomponents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the same time.  You can call either inject function you wish on it, but you can't inject it with compA then compB.  You could however make a componentC that builds off of subcomponents A and B and inject it with that.

Comment: I would appreciate a bit of explanation of why? Also can you please show me how to do that with subcomponents as i don't have any experience with them.

Comment: Why is philosophical-  the idea of injection is that it fills in all of the values.  So when Dagger sees that there's values it was supposed to inject that it doesn't know how to inject, it throws an exception.  That was a design decision of dagger, to throw an error rather than to partially inject.  Which for constructor based injection makes sense-  it doesn't now what to put for the other parameters.  As for subcomponents-  I'd google for them, I don't have the time right at the moment to put together an example.

Comment: Thanks, Yes you are right. The component will try to make graph and when it doesn't know how tio full fill an internal dependency it throws which is pretty fair deal. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do you have time now to put in a small example on how to do the above using subcomponents?